# cant find height for my cell

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uilabel

I know there are many links to get the height of the label within the cell. I have tried every thing .. nothing is working ..

My scenario is :

I have a cell , in this cell i have 6 labels , text within these labels are dynamic and coming from a web service.

I dont know what i am doing wrong , i have applied every thing to get the dynamic height right:

i have 2 issues:

1) when tableview loads first time heights of labels are not proper (its according to nib).
2) when i reload table view it gives me the dynamic height , but its not correct.

here is my code:

In controller where i am calculating to height of cell each time :

```
-(float)saltDetailsCellHeight : (HKDrugSaltInfoModel *)saltInfoModel
{
    UIColor *_black=[UIColor blackColor];
    UIColor *_lightGray = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0f];

    // salt Heading
    NSString * saltNameLabelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",saltInfoModel.saltName,saltInfoModel.strength];
    float hSaltNameLabelString =  [HKGlobal heightOfGivenText:saltNameLabelString ofWidth:300.0 andFont:font];

    // Salts string
    NSString * saltsString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pregnancy:%@ Lactation:%@ Lab:%@ Food:%@",saltInfoModel.ci_pg,
                               saltInfoModel.ci_lc,saltInfoModel.ci_lb,saltInfoModel.ci_fd];
    float hSaltsString =  [HKGlobal heightOfGivenText:saltsString ofWidth:300.0 andFont:font];

    // Usage Label
    NSString *usageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Typical Usage: %@",saltInfoModel.lc];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:usageString];
    NSInteger _stringLength=[usageString length];
    [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
    [attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, 14)];
    [attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_lightGray range:NSMakeRange(15, _stringLength-15)];
    float hUsageString =  [HKGlobal heightOfGivenText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)attrStr] ofWidth:300.0 andFont:font];


    // Side Effects label
    NSString *sideEffectsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Side Effects: %@",saltInfoModel.se];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrStrSide = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:sideEffectsString];
    NSInteger _stringLengthSE = [sideEffectsString length];
    [attrStrSide addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLengthSE)];
    [attrStrSide addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, 14)];
    [attrStrSide addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_lightGray range:NSMakeRange(15, _stringLengthSE-15)];
    float hSideEffectsString =  [HKGlobal heightOfGivenText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(NSString *)attrStrSide] ofWidth:300.0 andFont:font];


    // Drug Interaction Label
    NSString *drugInteractionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Drug Interaction: %@",saltInfoModel.di];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrdrugInteractionStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:drugInteractionString];
    NSInteger _strLenDrugInteraction = [drugInteractionString length];
    [attrdrugInteractionStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _strLenDrugInteraction)];
    [attrdrugInteractionStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, 18)];
    [attrdrugInteractionStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_lightGray range:NSMakeRange(18, _strLenDrugInteraction-18)];
    float hAttrdrugInteractionStr =  [HKGlobal heightOfGivenText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString*)attrdrugInteractionStr] ofWidth:300.0 andFont:font];

    // MechanismOfAction Label
    NSString *moaString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mechanism Of Action: %@",saltInfoModel.moa];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrMoaStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:moaString];
    NSInteger _strLenMoa=[moaString length];
    [attrMoaStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _strLenMoa)];
    [attrMoaStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, 21)];
    [attrMoaStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_lightGray range:NSMakeRange(21, _strLenMoa-21)];
    float hAttrMoaStr =  [HKGlobal heightOfGivenText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString*)attrMoaStr] ofWidth:300.0 andFont:font];

    arrayOFLabelsHeights  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:hSaltNameLabelString],
                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:hSaltsString],
                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:hUsageString],
                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:hSideEffectsString],
                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:hAttrdrugInteractionStr],
                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:hAttrMoaStr],
                             nil];

    float cellHeight = hSaltNameLabelString+10+hSaltsString+10+hUsageString+10+hSideEffectsString+10+hAttrdrugInteractionStr+10+hAttrMoaStr;

    return cellHeight;

}
```

and i am using above method in tableview:heightForRowAtIndexpath:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

            return [self saltDetailsCellHeight:[self.drugDetailModel.saltInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-3]];

}
```

And in cell for row at index path i am PASSSing the arrayOFLabelsHeights array , which contains the height of each label :

```
 HKMedicineDetailInfoCell *medicineDetailInfoCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
            if(medicineDetailInfoCell == nil)
            {
                medicineDetailInfoCell = (HKMedicineDetailInfoCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MedicineDetailInfoCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            //Check whether array contains any object or not
            if([self.drugDetailModel.saltInfoArray count] > 0)
            {
                [medicineDetailInfoCell customiseLabels:[self.drugDetailModel.saltInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-3] WithHeights:arrayOFLabelsHeights]; // since 3 rows are already there
            }
            return medicineDetailInfoCell;
```

And the method customiseLabels: is declared in my custom cell class like this (i think there would be code duplicacy but i have to do this, not able to find any other way):

```
-(void)customiseLabels:(HKDrugSaltInfoModel *)saltInfoModel WithHeights:(NSArray *)heightsArray
{

    UIColor *_black=[UIColor blackColor];
    UIColor *_lightGray = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    //Helvetica Neue
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0f];

    float h1 = [[heightsArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

    frameTemp = self.saltNameLabel.frame;
    frameTemp.size.height = h1;
    self.saltNameLabel.frame = frameTemp;
    self.saltNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",saltInfoModel.saltName,saltInfoModel.strength];


    frameTemp.origin.y += h1+10;

    float h2 = [[heightsArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    frameTemp.size.height = h2;
    self.secondDescriptiveLabel.frame = frameTemp;
    self.secondDescriptiveLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pregnancy:%@ Lactation:%@ Lab:%@ Food:%@",saltInfoModel.ci_pg,saltInfoModel.ci_lc,saltInfoModel.ci_lb,saltInfoModel.ci_fd];

    frameTemp.origin.y += h2+10;

    float h3 = [[heightsArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    frameTemp.size.height = h3;
    self.usageLabel.frame = frameTemp;

    // Usage Label
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Typical Usage: %@",saltInfoModel.lc];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
    NSInteger _stringLength=[str length];
    [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
    [attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, 14)];
    [attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_lightGray range:NSMakeRange(15, _stringLength-15)];
    self.usageLabel.attributedText = attrStr;


    frameTemp.origin.y += h3+10;

    float h4 = [[heightsArray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
    frameTemp.size.height = h4;
    self.sideEffectsLabel.frame = frameTemp;

    // Side Effects label
    NSString *sideEffectsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Side Effects: %@",saltInfoModel.se];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrSideEffectsStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:sideEffectsString];
    NSInteger _strLenSideEffects=[sideEffectsString length];
    [attrSideEffectsStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _strLenSideEffects)];
    [attrSideEffectsStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, 14)];
    [attrSideEffectsStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_lightGray range:NSMakeRange(14, _strLenSideEffects-14)];
    self.sideEffectsLabel.attributedText = attrSideEffectsStr;


    frameTemp.origin.y += h4+10;

    float h5 = [[heightsArray objectAtIndex:4] floatValue];
    frameTemp.size.height = h5;
    self.drugInteractionLabel.frame = frameTemp;

    // Drug Interaction Label
    NSString *drugInteractionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Drug Interaction: %@",saltInfoModel.di];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrdrugInteractionStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:drugInteractionString];
    NSInteger _strLenDrugInteraction=[drugInteractionString length];
    [attrdrugInteractionStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _strLenDrugInteraction)];
    [attrdrugInteractionStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, 18)];
    [attrdrugInteractionStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_lightGray range:NSMakeRange(18, _strLenDrugInteraction-18)];
    self.drugInteractionLabel.attributedText = attrdrugInteractionStr;

    frameTemp.origin.y += h5+10;

    float h6 = [[heightsArray objectAtIndex:5] floatValue];
    frameTemp.size.height = h6;
    self.moaLabel.frame = frameTemp;

    // MechanismOfAction Label
    NSString *moaString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mechanism Of Action: %@",saltInfoModel.moa];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrMoaStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:moaString];
    NSInteger _strLenMoa=[moaString length];
    [attrMoaStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _strLenMoa)];
    [attrMoaStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, 21)];
    [attrMoaStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_lightGray range:NSMakeRange(21, _strLenMoa-21)];
    self.moaLabel.attributedText = attrMoaStr;

    NSLog(@"height of cell : %f", frameTemp.origin.y + self.moaLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

Still i have large spaces in between labels , here is screenshot:

[image]
[image]

I have tried every thing .. and struggling with this issue for many hours (a small issue i think :( )

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where you are setting the height of the cell. You should not call some obscure function in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but return the height of the cell.

Ask your datasource for the necessary strings and then calculate the height the usual way, i.e. using `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`. The source of your problem is the convoluted code.